# Get values into a different table in different sheet

Tags: excel

I have a table (see screenshot) and I want to know how to get a table in a different sheet with first and only one instance of `Max Rank` (column B) and corresponding `Sum` (column E).

In other words a **table with 'Max Rank' with non empty 'Sum'**

I am new to Excel.

[image: Commercial Photography]

Here is the desired table below(screenshot):

[image: Commercial Photography]

Comment: Can you show desired output. Do you mean sum for each rank {1, 2, 3...} or just the highest rank and sum?

Comment: @AlexP Please check the desired table format. i want just the maximum rank and non empty sum.

Comment: Are your `Max Ranks` always known ahead of time e.g. range from 1 to 10? If so a `vlookup`is quite easy to implement...

Comment: Yes they are known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this -

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$14=G2)*$D$2:$D$14)
```

[image]